# How to use PHP CLI in C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, command-line-interface

I'm from China, so my english maybe is really poor. I will try my best to make you understand my question.
I want to use PHP CLI in my C# project.
I tried code like this

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
try
{
    p.Start();
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    p.WaitForExit(1000);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
    string text= reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (text.IndexOf(command) != -1)
    {
        int start = text.IndexOf(command) + command.Length;
        string endstring = rootpath + ">exit";
        int end = text.IndexOf(endstring);
        text = text.Substring(start, text.Length - start - endstring.Length).Trim();

        return text;
    }

    return "";
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    return "";
}
finally
{
    p.Close();
}
```

As the returned string is not what I need, I use substring to get the correct results, but sometimes I can't get what I really want.
I think my method might not be correct,but I can't find any information on the Internet.

Comment: Please format your question and wrap your code in code tags.

Comment: Please explain what the actual results are and expected results should be.

Answer (score 1):

If I go by your code example the question does not make sense.  However according to your question you can execute a PHP script from the CLI and collect the output using something like the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
string sOutput = "";

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "php.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f file.php";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

System.IO.StreamReader hOutput = proc.StandardOutput;

proc.WaitForExit(2000);

if(proc.HasExited)
   sOutput = hOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Half of this code is my own and the rest I derived from a [snippet](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/0b10ce4e-46fb-4e72-a542-d870af64c6aa.aspx) I found via [Google](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=capture+output+from+CLI+c%23).

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes ,thanks your help very much,I have resolved this problem use the similar method with yours thank you